# C Cast vs C++ Cast

Tags: c, c++, cast

Qual é a diferença entre utilizar o cast do C:

```
float t = 5.0f;
int v = (int)t;
```

Para o cast do C++:

```
float t = 5.0f;
int v = static_cast<int>(t);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `static_cast` do padrão `C++` é mais restritivo e só permite conversões entre tipos compatíveis. Essa compatibilidade é validada em tempo de compilação:

```
char c = 123;
int * p = static_cast<int*>(&c); // Erro em tempo de compilação!
```

O `cast` no estilo `C` permite conversões entre tipo incompatíveis sem nenhum tipo de verificação:

```
char c = 123;
int * p = (int*) &c;  // OK!
```

O `reinterpret_cast` do padrão `C++` se comporta de forma idêntica aos `casts`no estilo `C`, permitindo conversões entre tipos incompatíveis:

```
char c = 123;
int * p = reinterpret_cast<int*>(&c); // Conversão forçada: OK!
```

Evite usar `casts` em estilo `C` se você estiver usando um compilador `C++`, tente sempre substituí-lo por um `static_cast`, quando possível.

E se o intento for realmente uma conversão forçada de tipos, use `reinterpret_cast`.

Answer (score 2):

Existe uma diferença fundamental já que, como o nome diz, o *cast* do C++ é estático, ou seja é feito em tempo de compilação, não há custo externo e pode produzir um erro antes de gerar o executável.

De forma geral o mecanismo do C++ é mais seguro e não permite o que deve causar problemas. O compilador mais o mecanismo de *template* consegue indicar se há compatibilidade entre os tipos para o *cast* ser bem sucedido.

Em C é até possível que alguma otimização elimine custo de *runtime*, mas a princípio será realizado lá.

Algumas pessoas não gostam do estilo do C também porque não é fácil buscar no código. Claro que isto é um pouco falha dos IDEs.

Existem variações de *cast* em C++ cada um mais adequado que outro, e pode até fazer um *cast* dinâmico, se preciso. Assim fica mais legível e demonstra mais a intenção do que deseja, ainda que o resultado final muitas vezes seja o mesmo.

[Documentação do C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast).